# Keep Bootstrap Dropdown open in Navbar no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown menu nested in a navbar that I am opening during page load by adding the `open` class to the `li` element containing the dropdown menu.

I want this menu to stay open no matter what is clicked or where a user clicks on the page.  I have tried different solutions found on Stackoverflow.com to similar problems, but none of them are working.  They all seem to involve stopping the propagation of the click events from closing the menu.  I am using bootstrap v3.3.4.

EDIT
Here is the menu layout:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">menu1</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown open">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" id="catalogmenu" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;">menu 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">menu3</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">menu4</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:310px" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">go</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

EDIT 2
DanDavis suggestion in the comments is the way to go based on my testing.  Handling the events and formatting myself is easier in this case than relying on bootstraps native formatting and functionality.

Comment: copy the CSS rules for open, name them ".open2", and add "open2" to the class of the dropdown; works without scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This uses only css. [working demo](http://www.bootply.com/b6Rr8K4Gke)

Add a class to the dropdown ul (.stay-open)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu stay-open">
```

then apply style display block with !important

```
.stay-open {display:block !important;}
```

Comment: Works with css!

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that you are using a bootstrap dropdown, give this a shot:

```
$('li.dropdown').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.close = false; },
    "click":             function() { this.close = true; },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.close; }
});
```

The above implementation will hide the dropdown when it is clicked again. If you do not like that behavior, you can simply remove the first two lines (shown.bs.dropdown and click events) and simply return false for hide.bs.dropdown event.

Here is working proof [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/g7FsVljemh)

Here is a working proof [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7lap4GnAHa) that will always stay open

Comment: Just tried this.  I don't know if the events are firing.

Comment: @NinjaBomb Just updated and added a working proof through bootply

Comment: FYI - I just tested it in the demo and when I click the menu closes.

Comment: @NinjaBomb if you read the description, that's exactly what it says. It says to always return false if you don't want that behavior.